# Concurrent requests problem in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I face the following problem

```
function book($memberid, $classid){
if (!book){
 // update the db and change the book variable to true
}
}
```

My problem is 2 requests submitted at the same time.
The first request passes the line if (!book){ but not yet update the db. And at the same time, the second request runs the same function and also passes the line if (!book){. Therefore, the result is wrong.

I want to know how to solve this concurrency problem.
Lock the db? But I am afraid that it will affect the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need that variable?

The standard way of resolving concurrency problems when updating databases is to let the database handle it by means of transactions (which will impact performance in some cases, but so will a code only solution).

I'd like to see what goes inside the if (!book) clause.

EDIT: Why don't you change the db to make the (person,class) combination a unique key? That way you just physically cannot insert twice the same value in the table. I'm still taking wild guesses because it depends on the structure of the database. Also MySQL has a special syntax to do a conditional insert which would suit here. Check this [url](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,164551,164575#msg-164575).

Comment: if (!book) just selects from the db to see whether the person books a class. If the person doesn't book the class previously, then he can book the class. Otherwise, he is not allowed to book the class again.

Comment: Why don't you change the db to make the (person,class) combination a unique key? That way you just physically cannot insert twice the same value in the table. I'm still taking wild guesses because it depends on the structure of the database. Also MySQL has a special syntax to do a conditional insert which would suit here. Check http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,164551,164575#msg-164575

Answer (score 0):

If you [create an unique index(person,class)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) you can simply try to insert the new record without any previous tets. If there's already another record with the same values in (person,class) the new record will be rejected and MySQL raises a ["duplicate key" error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) which can be appropriately handled by your script:

```
if ( 1062===mysql_errno() ) {
  echo "you've already made a reservation for this lecture.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use

```
UPDATE x SET y WHERE z
```

then simply [check affected rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see whether anything changed? That way, MYSQL effectively does both the check and the actual data change in one smooth atomic transaction for you with no concurrency problems. (I'm basing this on the fact you use the word "update" and not "insert" in your Q; if it's a insert this approach won't work but VolkerK's would)

If you really must check by SELECT then write by UPDATE as 2 separate statements, then transactions are the only way to go. You mention locking the DB - note that that's not the only option available to you. If you use InnoDB tables there are many different levels you can use.

Comment: note: more detail would help; the exact SQL and table structure

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if one wants to protect a segment of code by concurrent accesses, one way is to use the functions provided by the library which comes along with the compiler, regarding the underliyng O.S.

In C/C++, the functions are similar to:

```
EnterCriticalSection ([Initialized]Section_ID);
< CODE_TO_PROTECT >
LeaveCriticalSection ([Initialized]Section_ID);
```

But maybe that, in your case, a way to increase the efficiency of your strategy is using the following modification (if available in your language):

```
global: 
bool book = TRUE;

function book($memberid, $classid){
  while (!book); \\ this waits until the variable 'book' isn't TRUE
  // eventually, release the control of the task scheduler with:
  // while (!book) Sleep (1); 
  // performing a check every each millisecond.

  // then, first of all, set the variable to FALSE
  book = FALSE;

  // update the db
  ...
  ...

  // finally, set the variable 'book' again to TRUE...
  book = TRUE;
 }
```